# How to get attribute value using SelectSingleNode?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am parsing a xml document, I need find out the gid (an attribute) value (3810).

Based on `SelectSingleNode()`. I found it is not easy to find the attribute name and it's value.

Can I use this method or must I switch to another way.

Attached is my code.

How can I use `book` obj to get the attribute value`3810` for `gid`. Thank you.

My test.xml file as below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
   <VersionInfo date="2007-11-28" version="1.0.0.2" />
   <Attributes>
      <AttrDir name="EFEM" DirID="1">
         <AttrDir name="Aligner" DirID="2">
            <AttrDir name="SequenceID" DirID="3">
               <AttrObj text="Slot01" gid="3810" unit="" scale="1" />
               <AttrObjCount value="1" />
           </AttrDir>
         </AttrDir>
      </AttrDir>
   </Attributes>
</root>
```

I wrote the test.cs as below

```cs
public class Sample
{    
    public static void Main()
    {    
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");

        XmlNode book;
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        book = root.SelectSingleNode("Attributes[AttrDir[@name='EFEM']/AttrDir[@name='Aligner']/AttrDir[@name='SequenceID']/AttrObj[@text='Slot01']]");

        Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML document....");
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

[Update 06/10/2010]

1. The xml file is a complex file. Included thousands of gids. But for each of Xpath, the gid is unique.
2. I load the xml file to a TreeView control. `this.treeView1.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterSelect);`. When `treeView1_AfterSelect` event occurred, the `e.Node.FullPath` will return as a String Value.
3. I parse the string Value `e.Node.FullPath`. Then I got the member of XPath Above. Then I tried to find which gid item was selected.

I need find the gid value as a return value indeed.

Answer (score 14):

You can write

```
XmlAttribute gidAttribute = (XmlAttribute)book.Attributes.GetNamedItem("gid");
String gidValue = null;
if (gidAttribute!=null)
    value = gidAttribute.Value;
```

Alternatively, expand the Xpath to fetch the attribute, e.g.

```
Attributes[AttrDir[@name='EFEM']/AttrDir[@name='Aligner']/AttrDir[@name='SequenceID']/AttrObj[@text='Slot01']]/@gid
```

If the @gid is unique, then you can simply use the Xpath

```
"//AttrObj[@gid='3810']"
```

To fetch the desired node with the given id. But note that each request will search through the entire  document. It will be more efficient to fetch all the nodes, and then put them in a map, keyed by id.

```
"//AttrObj[@gid]"
```

Use `XmlNode.SelectNodes` to fetch a list of all AttrObj with a @gid attribute.

Comment: Given the code in the question book.Attributes is empty (Count = 0).

Comment: btw, will throw `NullReferenceException` in case of not found

Comment: @mdma, I tried `book = root.SelectSingleNode("Attributes[AttrDir[@name='EFEM']/AttrDir[@name='Aligner']/AttrDir[@name='SequenceID']/AttrObj[@text='Slot01']/@gid]");`. the book obj works well. but 

Compiler Error for `XmlAttribute gidAttribute = book.Attributes.GetNamedItem("gid");`: *error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'System.Xml.XmlAttribute'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Comment: @mdma, I can't use `"//AttrObj[@gid='3810']"` . Event though gid is unique in my XPath. But the gid value is a return value as I expressed before.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the cast. (Just as the error said.) See the first line of my answer code.

Comment: @mdma After updated my code.  Compile successfully but, `(XmlAttribute)book.Attributes.GetNamedItem("gid")` still return **null**.  And for **book.Attributes**, I add watch and found `System.Collections.ICollection.Count = 0`.

Answer (score 5):

You can query `XmlDocument` itself not `DocumentRoot`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode book = doc.SelectSingleNode("..");
if (book != null)
{
    XmlAttribute gid = book.Attributes["gid"];
    if (gid != null)
    {
       string value = gid.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the code in the question `book.Attributes` is empty (Count = 0).

Comment: Hello. From `book.Attributes.Count = 0`, can't find the `gid` during run time.

Comment: Acturally, there are thousands of gids in my real xml file. I'd like to parse the element layer with `selectSingleNode()`. I think it's a fast method for my case. Then I can find the unique gid.

Comment: @Nano: So please describe more what is your main problem finding `gid` using `SelectSingleNode` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was they your XPath was all wrong.  You had this:

```
Attributes[AttrDir[@name='EFEM']/AttrDir[@name='Aligner']/AttrDir[@name='SequenceID']/AttrObj[@text='Slot01']]
```

which would either select or not select the Attributes element depending on whether all the names matched up.  This XPath should take you directly to the gid attribute you want:

```
Attributes/AttrDir[@name='EFEM']/AttrDir[@name='Aligner']/AttrDir[@name='SequenceID']/AttrObj[@text='Slot01']/@gid
```