# Getting attribute of element in XPath

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to learn web-scraping. Therefore, I started practicing. I am trying to get data-ad-id from `HTML` using `XPath`.

`HTML` structure like this:

```
<body id="z1234">
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="g-row">
            <div class="g-col-9">
                <div class="cBox cBox--content cBox--resultList">
                    <div class="cBox-body cBox-body--resultitem dealerAd rbt-reg rbt-no-top"><a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result-item" href="url" data-ad-id="248059713"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

XPath for `<a class="link--muted no--text--decoration result item" >` is `//*[@id="z1234"]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[11]/a`. If I choose different car, only last div changes.

According to this I write `C#` code:

```
var url = "https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED&isSearchRequest=true&maxPowerAsArray=KW&maxPrice=10000&minPowerAsArray=KW&minPrice=10000&scopeId=C";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(sourceCode);




            var rows = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='z1234']/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[11]");


            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var id = row.SelectSingleNode("a[@data-ad-id]").InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("id:" + id);
            }
        }
```

I cannot get anything from this Node. It is null. How can I get data-ad-id?

**EDIT**
I change my C# code:

```
var rows = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@data-ad-id]")[0];
var id = rows.Attributes["data-ad-id"].Value;
```

Now I can get `data-ad-id.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code of the site, I could sense that you have no innertext for that "A" tag. It just contains DIV and IMG tags.

You will need to fetch data-ad-id using

```
//a[@data-ad-id]/@data-ad-id
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I tried this, but, I get `car name` instead of `data-ad-id`. @Ganesh Pandhere

Comment: I am not sure how the C# code is written. But I have given the code to fetch value of attribute which we do normally by the way I mentioned.

Comment: I hope it worked for you @heyaa

Otherwise I tried finding something related to SelectSingleNode for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004587/how-to-get-attribute-value-using-selectsinglenode

Comment: When I started to try, `[@id="z1234"]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[11]/a`  only last div (for this case : `div[11]` ) changes  in XPath.  Div was  increasing one by one. However now, it increasing sequentially. How can I get each i in `div[i]` . @Ganesh Pandhere